# Show that the unit quaternions form a group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification, quaternions, spheres

Here is the question I want to answer $(d)$ in it:

Define $E \in GL_{2}(\mathbb{R})$ by $E = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & -1 \\
1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}$ and let $\mathcal{R} = \{aI + bE| a,b \in \mathbb{R}\} \subset M_{2}(\mathbb{R}).$

$(a)$ Show that $\mathcal{R} \cong \mathbb{C}$ as rings (so $\mathcal{R}$ is a field). Which matrices correspond to the subgroup $S^{1} \subset \mathbb{C}^{*}$?

$(b)$ Let $\mathbb{H} \subset M_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be the set of matrices of the form:  $$ \begin{pmatrix}
z & - \bar{\omega} \\
\omega & \bar{z} 
\end{pmatrix} \quad \quad z, \omega \in \mathbb{C}$$Show that  $\mathbb{H}$ is a division ring. ( $\mathbb{H}$ is called the \textbf{quaternion algebra}).

$(c)$ Find a way to represent $\mathbb{H}$ as a subring of $M_{4}(\mathbb{R}).$(Hint: Combine parts $(a)$ and $(b)$)

$(d)$ The unit quaternions are quaternions of determinant 1. Show that the unit quaternions form a group, thereby giving a group structure on the $3-$sphere $S^3 \subset \mathbb{R}^4.$

**And here is a solution I found on the internet:**

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

**My questions are:**

1- Why the solution considered $\mathbb{H}$ as quaternions?

2- Why the solution took the operation as multiplication and not addition?

3- Where is the proof that matrix multiplication is associative?

Comment: Have you read and understood this proof? Do you have any questions about it? That would make for a better question than "Read this proof and tell me if it is correct".

Comment: Ok I am sorry @LeeMosher I will edit my question.

Comment: @LeeMosher I do not understand the induced group structure on $S^3$ why it has the $-1$ sign in it i.e. why taking inverses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Recall from part (b) that $\mathbb H$ is called the *quaternion algebra.*
   Its elements are quaternions.

Personally I sympathize with your doubt about the definition of a *quaternion.*
I would have preferred a more explicit definition of the term *quaternion* by itself (as opposed to the compound term *quaternion algebra*). We cannot always assume that mathematical terms combine or uncombine in intuitively obvious ways.
Possibly your internet source (where you got the solution) has a better definition if you look for it.

2. Take a unit quaternion $h$ and add it to itself: $h + h.$ The result is not a unit quaternion, as you can confirm by finding its determinant. So unit quaternions are not closed under addition, and cannot be a group under addition.
3. Associativity is a very basic property of matrix multiplication. See [https://people.math.carleton.ca/~kcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk05/05_associativity_of_matrix_multiplication.html](https://people.math.carleton.ca/%7Ekcheung/math/notes/MATH1107/wk05/05_associativity_of_matrix_multiplication.html) for example.

Comment: I also have a question about the induced group structure on $S^3,$ why the answer expressed it in terms of the inverses?

Comment: If $p$ and $q$ are elements of $S^3,$ you need to map them to $U$ so that you can use multiplication of two elements of $U$. The mapping $\psi|_U$ is from $U$ to $S^3$ so we need the inverse so that we can go in the opposite direction. But I think the proof missed the final step, which is that after we get two elements of $U$ and multiply them to produce a resulting element of $U$, that element needs to be mapped back to $S^3$. I think this means we really want $p*q = \psi|_U(( \psi|_U)^{-1}(p)( \psi|_U)^{-1}(q))$.